# Reading AT Commands result codes

Tags: c#, command, at-command

I'm working on a project witch involves sending `AT` commands to mobiles phones modems and receiving their result codes.
I already succeeded on sending the at commands, but what i couldn't figure out is reading the result codes from the commands like when you send "at" it returns "OK" and if you send "at+cbc" it return the battery status.
I tried using Read and ReadLine and ReadExisting after sending the command but it didn't work, I also tried creating an event for the received data and using those functions but it didn't work either.
This is my source code i hope you would give me some help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class check : Form
    {
        SerialPort sp;

        public check()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM3";
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.ReadTimeout = 3000;
            sp.WriteTimeout = 3000;
            //sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(!sp.IsOpen)
                {
                    sp.Open();
                }
                sp.WriteLine(tbCmd+"\r\n");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                tbStatus.Text = sp.ReadLine();      
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                tbStatus.Text = "Error!\r\n" + ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        //void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    tbStatus.Text = sp.ReadExisting();
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: @motevallizadeh : probably the TextBox containing the AT command that should be sent through the COM port...

Answer (score 0):

```
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.EventType != SerialData.Chars)
        {
            tbStatus.Text = "IGNORED: " + e.EventType.ToString();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            int nBytesToRead = sp.BytesToRead;
            char[] receivedData = new char[nBytesToRead];
            sp.Read(receivedData, 0, nBytesToRead);
            tbStatus.Text = "RECEIVED: " + new string(receivedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tbStatus.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i read in Nokia forum  that Nokia phones series 60 do not supports read sms message commands and this at commands not works on Nokia phones